# Getting data out of a Yesod route

Tags: haskell, yesod

Suppose I have a Yesod routes file of the form:

```
/foo/#Value
```

Is there a handler, or at least a utility function, that can parse the Value out of a fully formed request?  What I mean is, I don't want to have to figure out what the "current" route is at write time or compile time, when I write

```
myHander = do
  value <- mysteriousHandlerThatOutputsValueFromRequest
  doStuff value
```

I am aware of the PathPieces typeclasses.  And I am guessing that because of the architecture, what I'm asking for isn't "directly" possible.  Should I just iterate fromPathPiece on the tails until I find a Just?

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood something, but assuming that `myHandler` is a handler for path `/foo/#Value`, you can deduce that the type of `myHandler` is `Value -> Handler Html` – the `Handler Html` is taken just as an example, it can be something else, depending on your concrete use. Your handler's first argument is the value of type `Value` and there's no need for any parsing:

```
myHander value = do
  doStuff value
```

Comment: Yeah, whats missing is that entryPointHandler is defined in a type class and takes no arguments.  So a definition of it must examine the request to get a value.  I am reconsidering the definition of the type class to let me pass in an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [parseRoute](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/yesod-core/Yesod-Core.html#v%3aparseRoute). [decodePath](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/http-types/Network-HTTP-Types-URI.html#v%3adecodePath) will likely help you out as well.

Comment: Your links are broken!